# php tools to detect bottle neck

Tags: php

I'm developing a web-application with PHP and some libraries. The problem is that i need to generate some excel files, and this procedure takes a lot of time. Can you help me with some tools to identify where my application spends a lot of time,. Can you recommend a php tool which will help me to detect the bottle necks?

ps: the lib that I use for generating the excel files is [PHPExcel](http://www.codeplex.com/PHPExcel).

Answer (score 1):

[Xdebug](http://xdebug.org/) or Zend Debugger

They allow you to profile your application and will generate comprehensive lists about which functions have been called and how long they took to execute. XDebug is free. [Zend Debugger requires Zend Studio or Eclipse](http://www.zend.com/en/community/pdt).

Answer (score 0):

See our [SD PHP Profiler](http://www.semanticdesigns.com/Products/Profilers/PHPProfiler.html).  This will show you graphically where your code spends most of its time.

Comment: Don't understand the ding.  The answer directly addresses the question.